# Spark Sql sort operation is not working properly

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to sort a dataframe with **sort** function but it dosen't sort properly and seems it is sorting in chunks. Maybe it is sorting the individual partitions and not combing the sort.However where clause is working fine

I have used sort function and plain sql query also , none of them seems to work

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutils");    
val tempDir = "file:///c:/temp/spark-warehouse"    
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
// Create a SparkContext using every core of the local machine, named RatingsCounter

val sparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("AppStore")
  .master("local[2]")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", tempDir)
  .getOrCreate()

var appStoreDF = sparkSession.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("../AppleStore.csv") 
appStoreDF.show(10)
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

appStoreDF.select("size_bytes").sort(desc("size_bytes")).show(10)  // Gives unsorted results
```

this is the output I get:

```
+----------+
|size_bytes|
+----------+
|  99992576|
|  99978240|
| 999398400|
|  99890176|
|  99851264|
|  99829760|
|  99796992|
| 997171200|
| 997129216|
|  99691520|
+----------+
```

Comment: what type is the size_bytes column

Comment: can you show what displays `appStoreDF.select("size_bytes").sort(desc("size_bytes")).printSchema` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the type to `Integer` and see the order will be as you expect:

```
appStoreDF
  .withColumn("size_bytes", col("size_bytes").cast(sql.types.IntegerType))
  .select("size_bytes")
  .sort(desc("size_bytes"))
  .show(10)
```

Output:

```
+----------+
|size_bytes|
+----------+
| 999398400|
|  99978240|
|  99890176|
|       ...|
+----------+
```

The `size_bytes` column type is String. You can verify this by:

```
appStoreDF.select("size_bytes").printSchema // size_bytes: string
```

When you sort strings in desc mode they are sorted in lexicographically order: 99978240 before 999398400.

Comment: thanks i did that and it was a string . But how come where condition was working fine on a string .. like where size_bytes > 10000 ?

Comment: @amol, In that case, more than probably, there is simply an implicit cast to Integer performed by the engine